# FTP <ipadress>:<port number> in Raspberry Pi Error

Tags: linux, macos, wireless-networking, ftp, raspberry-pi

**Objective: Send files from Raspberry Pi terminal to Android FTP server.**

Mac, Raspberry Pi and Android all are in the same network.

I have installed 'WiFi FTP Server' on my android phone with server url `ftp://192.168.43.107:2221 Userid: xxxxxx password: xxxxx`

I can access this FTP server through Filezilla client on my Mac.

How do I access it from Raspberry Pi terminal and Mac terminal using ftp?

I have already tried:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ftp 192.168.43.107
ftp: connect: Connection refused

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ftp 192.168.43.107:2221
ftp: 192.168.43.107:2221: Name or service not known
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Use a space instead of a colon: `ftp 192.168.43.107 2221`

Answer (score 0):

found it.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST="192.168.43.107 2221"
USER=xxxxx
PASSWORD=xxxxx

ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
ls
EOF
```

And run the shell script